# How to setup giver and receivers with junction object

Tags: junction-object

The contacts in our SF instance can give gifts from other contacts or receive gifts from contacts.

I need a way to represent who gave to whom.

Would the following scenario work?

1. Create an object "givers" with a lookup field named "giver" pointing to the contacts object
2. Create an object "receivers" with a lookup field named "received from" pointing to the contacts object
3. Create a junction object named "who gave to who" and create two master detail fields to the two aforementioned objects.

Is this scenario correct and if not, what would I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one object in between, not three. Have a "junction" from `Contact` to `Contact`. I put air quotes around the term because I think you will have to use `Lookup` relationships since you are using the same object twice.

```
 ---------           ----------           ---------
| Contact |  <----  | Junction |  ---->  | Contact |
 ---------           ----------           ---------
   Giver                                   Receiver
```

With this setup, you would simply name the junction object `Gift__c`.

I would really strongly advise you to always give your objects a singular name. In your question, you talk about naming your unnecessary intermediary objects `Givers__c` and `Receivers__c`. If these objects *were* necessary, it would be far preferable to instead name them `Giver__c` and `Receiver__c`.

Comment: What if I wanted it that if the contact is deleted, the giver and taker with that value also gets deleted. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is not a complicated requirement. Also it is a completely separate question.